# sub-package not importable after installation

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I've got a package-project with the following structure:

```
project/
   src/
      handlers/
         __init__.py
         sqlserver.py # contains the SqlServerHandler class
      __init__.py
      project.py # contains other classes
   pyproject.toml
```

with `pyproject.toml` as:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "project"
version = "1.0.0"
requires-python = ">=3.10.5"
authors = [{ name = "me" }]
dependencies = [
    "pyodbc"
]
```

I can successfuly install it with `pip install c:\path\to\project`, but when I try to use the `handlers` module it doesn't show up as if it didn't existed.

```py
from project import SomeClass # works fine
from project.handlers.sqlserver import SqlServerHandler # does not exist
```

I've checked what the installer generates and the `build\lib` folder contains everythig so I don't quite understand what I am missing and how I can make sure the sub-modules are also importable?

Comment: Can you import `project.handlers.sqlserver`?

Comment: @jkr nope, that's the issue I'm trying to solve. Neither `from` nor `import` works. When I run the project importing this module forefully it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.handlers'; 'project' is not a package`

Comment: do you have a`projects.py` file in your current directory? maybe try moving to a new directory and try again?

Comment: Seems like the instructions to tell setuptools which Python importable packages should be added to the distribution packages (sdist wheel) and should be installed are missing in `pyproject.toml`. See here: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#package-discovery and https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution absolutely doesn't make any sense, but after many trial and errors I finally figured out how to fix that.

---

First I navigated to the links provided by @sinoroc and changed the project structre as described here to make use of the autodiscovery: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout

Since this still wasn't enough, I tried a lot of other ideas including adding this `setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
   packages=["src.project.handlers", "src.project.handlers.sqlserver"]
)
```

Well, no luck with that.

Finally, pretty furstrated, I left the `setup` method empty and it worked!!!

```
project/
   src/
      project/ # <-- new level
         handlers/
            __init__.py
            sqlserver.py # contains the SqlServerHandler class
         __init__.py
         project.py # contains other classes
   pyproject.toml
   setup.py # <-- new with empty setup()
```

Now PyCharm recognizes all sub-packages and the app runs without errors.

---

Comment: @sinoroc: I did it! Thx for the links though I have no idea what's going on here LOL It's funny that they consider `pyproject.toml` the new packaging system and `setup.py` legacy, but nearly all the new configuration is in BETA and doesn't work and you still need to provide the old `setup.py`. Isn't pyton great? :P